# Run several Appium Tests after another with nodejs

Tags: node.js, appium

I'm trying to build a testsuite in which are eg. 5 testfiles named Test1.js - Test5.js.
I want to execute the testsuite which then runs Test1.js.
After Test1.js is complete it should run Test2.js.

I tried to do it with require()

```
.fin(function() {
      console.log("Test succeeded")
        require('./Test2.js')
        return browser.quit();
```

But if the require is before the browser.quit() I can't execute the second test because the Appium server is still up and running, and after browser.quit() the require() doesn't get called at all.

I am fairly new to Appium, nodejs and Javascript in general so maybe I have overlooked something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself. The problem wasn't the calling of the function but the server arguments.
I used `"sessionOverride":false` instead of `"sessionOverride":true`.

Comment: could you please provide the details or link where I can check the args?